# matrix synapse - How to get Access to database

Tags: matrix-synapse

i experiment a bit with matriy synapse. It´s working local on my root server, i can use matrix clients to get access. So this is working. I want to go a little bit deeper.

I have two questions:

1. Where i can find a fully database schema. I do some research, but could not find it.
2. How do i get direct Access to the (postgreSQL) database - best with remote -, so i can use SQL Commands to alter tables, insert data and so on, like in every database. In the moment it does not work. Maybe nginx is blocking to access from "outside".

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1**

I don't think there is an official database schema but you can find a partial one on github :

https://github.com/matrix-org/synapse/issues/934#issuecomment-612384833

**Question 2**

I assume you access your server via CLI, you can access your postgres database by switching to the postgres user:

```
su - postgres
```

Then launch the postgres terminal:

```
psql
```

(documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html)

When you're in the terminal, you can use SQL queries.